# Erlang does not execute httpc:request/4 function

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I wrote a module for offline message hook for ejabberd, and function call works. I can see the function start and finished in logs but I don't have HTTP request log on my backend server. I tested the code in Erlang shell and it works.

```
?INFO_MSG("Offline message start", []),
httpc:request(post, {PostUrl, [{"X-Auth",API_Key}], "application/json", list_to_binary(RequestBody)},[],[]),
?INFO_MSG("Offline message finished", []),
        ok
```

any Idea?!

Comment: What is the return value of `httpc:request`? Might be worth logging it as well.

Comment: backend always return 200, I tested it in the Erlnag shell, but in the module, I do not receive even a request from this code.

Comment: That's why it might be worth checking in the module, since there seems to be a difference between the two. Perhaps it returns an error when you run the call from within the module?

Comment: Please provide the module you are calling from, if possible. Is this a gen_server, fsm, or just invoked from console or module? There could be any number of reasons for this call not getting hit.